# Delete data from two tables with one query?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to delete data's from two tables:

something like this:

```
$rez = mysql_query("delete from slike where slike_id='$del' or delete from foto where foto_id='$del'");
```

How i can to do that? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query

Comment: yes you can. create a stored proc and call it !

Comment: But situtation is small specify, i have one list where i select data's from tables and show them both into list, i now want when i press delete to delete some selected value from list...

Comment: this doesn't work

$del = $_POST['list'];
  $rez = mysql_query("delete from slike where slike_id='$del'; delete from foto where foto_id=$del");

Comment: i need something like "or", if some of two queries is possible then run it ...

Answer (score 0):

you should first search what you are asking ..

```
DELETE  FROM slike  INNER JOIN foto on  slike.slike_id= foto.foto_id where slike.slike_id='$del'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't posible unless you use [MySQL triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) or have [relation between columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383612/setting-up-table-relations-what-do-cascade-set-null-and-restrict-do).

Comment: it has a relation slike_id = foto_id according to sql_query.

Comment: SOLVED, i delete foto table, and just add tho new columns in slike table, and set all columns to allow null.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rez = mysql_query("DELETE FROM slike WHERE slike_id='$del' AND TRUE=DELETE FROM foto WHERE foto_id='$del'");
```