# Symfony2 delete entities, cascade exception

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called **Step2** (has multiple selectedriskassesments entities which is a RiskAssestment entity with an extra field):

```
......................
    manyToMany:
       selectedriskassesments:
         targetEntity: **SelectedRiskAssesment**
         joinTable:
           name: step2_selected_risk_assesments
           joinColumns:
             step2_id:
               referencedColumnName: id
           inverseJoinColumns:
             selected_risk_id:
               referencedColumnName: id 
         cascade: ["persist","remove"]
..............................
```

and **SelectedRiskAssesment** entity has:

```
 manyToOne:
        risk_assesment:
            targetEntity: RiskAssestment
            inversedBy: selectedriskassesment
            joinColumn:
                name: risk_assesment
                referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: true
```

This is part of a survey, and I want to **delete Step2** entity and it`s **selectedriskassesments** but I get :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`phsafety`.`step2_selected_risk_assesments`, CONSTRAINT `FK_FAFC9298EA71C84F` FOREIGN KEY (`selected_risk_id`) REFERENCES `selectedriskassesment` (`id`))
```

I have tried to use **orphanRemoval: true** to unbind from the **RiskAssestment** entity...any help would be awesome

Comment: http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else

Comment: Found somewhat similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780995/doctrine2-cannot-delete-an-entity-with-a-unidirectional-onetomany-relation

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the Step2 entity:

```
  manyToMany:
       selectedriskassesments:
         targetEntity: **SelectedRiskAssesment**
         joinTable:
           name: step2_selected_risk_assesments
           joinColumns:
             step2_id:
               referencedColumnName: id
           inverseJoinColumns:
             selected_risk_id:
               referencedColumnName: id 
               onDelete: CASCADE
         cascade: ["persist","remove"]
```

Had to add **onDelete: CASCADE**, inspiration by

- Elnur Abdurrakhimov