# Doctrine2 delete issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

From previously question of mine ([Symfony2 delete entities, cascade exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804073/symfony2-delete-entities-cascade-exception))

Having this entity:

```
Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\Step2:
    type: entity
    table: step2
    repositoryClass: Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\Step2Repository  
    manyToMany:
       selectedriskassesments:
         targetEntity: SelectedRiskAssesment
         joinTable:
           name: step2_selected_risk_assesments
           joinColumns:
             step2_id:
               referencedColumnName: id
           inverseJoinColumns:
             selected_risk_id:
               referencedColumnName: id 
               onDelete: CASCADE
         cascade: ["persist","remove"]
```

SelectedRiskAssesment :

```
Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\SelectedRiskAssesment:
    type: entity
    table: selectedriskassesment
    repositoryClass: Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\SelectedRiskAssesmentRepository

    manyToOne:
        risk_assesment:
            targetEntity: RiskAssestment
            inversedBy: selectedriskassesment
            joinColumn:
                name: risk_assesment
                referencedColumnName: id
            cascade: ["detach"]
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        answer:
            type: boolean
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

On deleting Step 2 it deletes all the `selectedriskassesments` **it removes my RiskAssestment entity which I don`t want**.

If I remove **onDelete: CASCADE** it will generate an exception, tried to put **cascade: ["detach"]** but still nothing

Comment: I resolved this by a fake delete, assigning the Survey entity to a deleted user(not visible in the app), a bug can still be a feature :)