# Delete rows with foreign key in PostgreSQL Flask

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, flask-migrate

I want to delete a row from my model which has ForeignKey with postgresql. But I got this error:

> **IntegrityError**: (IntegrityError) update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "users_bestfriend_id_fkey" on table "users" DETAIL: Key (id)=(3) is still referenced from table "users". 'DELETE FROM users WHERE users.id = %(id)s' {'id': 3}

I think to solve it I should use CASCADE but don't know how to use it in my model so thanks if u help :)

---

**model.py**:

```
friends = db.Table('friends',
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
db.Column('friend_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
)

class Users(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True)
   age= db.Column(db.Integer )
   email = db.Column(db.String(50),index=True, unique= True)
   bestfriend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))


   is_bestfriend = db.relationship( 'Users', uselist=False, remote_side=[id], post_update=True)
```

**view.py**:

```
# delete user profile
@layout.route('/delete/<int:id>')
@login_required
def delete(id):
  user = Users.query.get_or_404(id)
  if g.user.id == user.id:
           flash('You are not allow to delete yourself.')

  else:
      db.session.delete(user)
      db.session.commit()
      flash('delete done.')
  return redirect(url_for('layout.user', id=id, page=1, sortby='normal'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html) is pretty clear about how to specify integrity constraints for columns in SQLAlchemy.

You should specify `ondelete` constraint as `SET NULL` for your `bestfriend_id` attribute, so when a `user` is deleted from table, his friends shouldn't get deleted along with him.

```
bestfriend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), nullable=True)
```

I don't know if **Flask** automatically alters the column when you made a change on that so I think you should also update the column manually.

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN users_bestfriend_id DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT users_bestfriend_id_fkey, ADD CONSTRAINT users_bestfriend_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (bestfriend_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

You want want to look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383612/setting-up-table-relations-what-do-cascade-set-null-and-restrict-do) or the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for further information about types of referential integrity constraints.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it should be ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN users_bestfriend_id DROP NOT NULL; and then  ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT users_bestfriend_id_fkey, ADD CONSTRAINT users_bestfriend_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (bestfriend_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
@ozgur thnx for ur help